# Skip blank row in loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have code where I want to hide all rows that contain zero. I don't want to hide any of the other rows which may have text or numbers in them, or be blank. I have been able to get the zero rows to hide and leave the other filled in rows. However, it hides the blank rows which I don't want. What am I missing?

```
Dim t As Range, u As Range
Set u = Range("E6:E300")

For Each t In u
    If t = 0 Then
        t.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf IsEmpty(t.Value) = True Then
    End If
Next t
```

Comment: `If Not IsEmpty(t.Value) And t = 0 Then`.

Comment: You can speed this up by just filtering on `0` and then hiding the resultant data set

Comment: @BigBen Thanks so much.